# Wordpress website renders differently on devices apart from the local server

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using my laptop as a test environment for a wordpress website before I move it to an online server. I have this setup with a xampp sever running on the local machine. Wordpress is installed and running a theme which I have modified somewhat. When I navigate to the website from the local machine by going to 'localhost', the website displays correctly, however if I navigate to the website from another device whether it may be a computer, phone or tablet, the website seems to exclude css styling and only displays plain html. Any insights would be appreciated.

I know that with some browsers, sites in your local intranet except localhost are rendered differently. I am not sure whether this is the issue here. I am using Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 dev-m

Comment: Are you trying to access localhost from another computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're accessing the site on another machine, open up the developer tools in your browser and see where the link to your CSS is pointing at.

It sounds like that CSS URL is hard-coded to be pointing at localhost (which would explain why it only works on your machine). It could also be the case that you have set your site's domain to be localhost in Wordpress which may be using that to render the URLs.

Double check your Wordpress settings, and also your theme's code.

Comment: Yes. chrome reports errors pointing to localhost. How would i change this setting?

Comment: You may need to alter the theme directly - but it may simply be in the website settings. I've not actually used Wordpress all that much :(